# Function with variable arguments runtime error

Tags: c++, c

I have written this function to calculate the average of some floats.But it has a runtime error at the last line of the while in "average" function.What's the problem with it?

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>



float average(float first , ...)
{
    int count = 0;
    float sum = 0 , i = first;

    va_list marker;

    va_start(marker , first);
    while(i != -1)
    {
        sum += i;
        count++;
        i = va_arg(marker , float);
    }

    va_end(marker);
    return(sum ? (sum / count) : 0);
}


int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    float avg = average(12.0f , 34.0f);

    printf("The average is : %f\n" , avg);
    scanf("a\n");
}
```

Comment: From personal experience I have found that functions that have a variable number of arguments cause more trouble than they are worth - especially if using C++ as there are better (IMHO) ways around this.

Comment: In particular using `-1` as a sentinel is really bad design, this might be a valid value. Since all your parameters are supposed to have the same type, C++ as well as C offer you better alternatives for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to end the call with a `-1`, so your `while` loop causes undefined behaviour because it tries to keep getting more arguments than you passed. It should be:

```
float avg = average(12.0f, 34.0f, -1f);
```

Also, `float` arguments are promoted to `double` when being passed to variadic functions, so you can't use `float` with `va_arg`. You should be using `double` for all this:

```
double average(double first, ...)
{
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0, i = first;

    va_list marker;

    va_start(marker, first);
    while(i != -1)
    {
        sum += i;
        count++;
        i = va_arg(marker, double);
    }

    va_end(marker);

    return sum ? sum / count : 0;
}

double avg = average(12.0, 34.0, -1.0);
```

Comment: It worked.But is there anyway to not use -1 in passed arguments?

Comment: @Arman-aegit the function needs to somehow know when to stop extracting arguments (i.e. when to stop the `while` loop). So you either have to give a value at the end like you are doing now, or do something like add a first argument that gives the number of arguments you want to sum. So it'd be like `double average(int count, ...)` and you could do `double avg = average(3, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);`. Unfortunately there is no automatic way to know how many arguments were passed.

Answer (score 4):

The function loops until it sees a `-1`, and the caller is not supplying the `-1`.

The man page on my box promises "random errors":

> ```
> va_arg()
>    ...
>    If  there  is  no  next argument, or if type is not compatible with the
>    type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the  default
>    argument promotions), random errors will occur.
> ```

Try:

```
float avg = average(12.0f, 34.0f, -1f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to pass -1 as the last arg to stop the while loop?

Also, I believe floats are converted to doubles when using VAs, so changing float to double would be good...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do not have a terminate for your while loop. You are checking for `-1` but never pass in `-1`. You need to call your `average` function as

```
float avg = average(12.0f ,34.0f, -1);
```

There is a runtime example of this example at [va_arg, va_end, va_start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) that shows almost exactly your code, but using `int` instead of `float` for the values.